# TikZ \foreach loop with \csname macro list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have a problem with a macro-defined list in a TikZ foreach loop. The macro is built by `\csname`...`\endcsname`.
I've played around with multiple `\expandafter` or ##1 instead of #1, but with no success: The list of elements is not considered as of multiple elements then as a complete string.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% Macro to read in configuration parameters
\newcommand*\ReadCfg[3]{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname#1#2list\endcsname{#3}%
}

% Provide list for upper positions (this macro will be looped by \foreach)
% \jobname is 'AUT'
\providecommand\ListUpper{%
    \expandafter\csname\jobname upperlist\endcsname%
}

% This configuration will be later provided by external file
\ReadCfg{AUT}{upper}{Elem1,Elem2,Elem3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \e in \ListUpper {
        \typeout{***\space\e} % \e is interpreted as "Elem1,Elem2,Elem3" instead of single elements
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, how can I loop throu the list of elements?

Thank you!

Comment: When using a macro in a list then it is expanded just once to get to the actual list.  Yours needs expanding several times (I think three: `\ListUpper` -> `\expandafter\csname ...` -> `\documentupperlist` -> `Elem1,Elem2,Elem3`). So you'll need to do a bit of pre-processing to shorten that sequence.  Will your list contain macros itself or will it be just strings?  If the latter, simplest might be to do a `\edef\ListUpper{...}` just before the `\foreach`.  It depends slightly on how automated you want it to be.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: the list contains no macros, just strings. I'm using the solution from Steven B. Segletes below, which works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% Macro to read in configuration parameters
\newcommand*\ReadCfg[3]{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname#1#2list\endcsname{#3}%
}

% Provide list for upper positions (this macro will be looped by \foreach)
% \jobname is 'AUT'
\providecommand\ListUpper{%
  \csname\jobname upperlist\endcsname%
}

% This configuration will be later provided by external file
\ReadCfg{AUT}{upper}{Elem1,Elem2,Elem3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\tmpA{\ListUpper}
  \foreach \e in \tmpA {
        \typeout{***\space\e} % \e is interpreted as "Elem1,Elem2,Elem3" instead of single elements
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

From AUT.log:

[image]

Comment: Once you have the `\edef\tmpA{\ListUpper}` then you don't need the other `\def\tmpB` stuff, you can go with `\foreach \e in \tmpA`.  `\foreach` will do *one* expansion of a macro to get a list.

Comment: I just saw your solution, and I'm going with that. I've putted a TikZ node inside the foreach loop and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewStacey.  I have revised the answer based on your comment.